# HTML returned from Node js HTTP request is different than the HTML returned from browser request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, httprequest, cheerio

I am facing a strange behavior when I am requesting HTML page using Nodejs. The response returned (in HTML) is not the same when I request the page using the browser. Mainly the images SRC is different in both cases.

The code is below with screenshot of the returned page: (I tried using axios, needlejs,,requestsjs and puppeteerjs with the same issue)

```
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

axios.get('https://www.amazon.de/dp/B079N6SKDD')
  .then(function (response) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    let dpDecription = $("#aplus3p_feature_div").html()
    console.log(dpDecription);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

This will return the div as this (without images) and the images SRC has "grey-pixel" within the name:
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/common/grey-pixel.gif

[image: HTML without images]

When I get the same page using my browser I see the div with images normally and img SRC is correctly referring the img source:
https://www.amazon.de/dp/B079N6SKDD --> Produktinformation (product information in English)

[image: Normal HTML]

How can I resolve this issue? I need to be able to return the div with the images using Nodejs and cheerio.

Comment: It's probably a different user agent string. A misconfigured server might respond to a request with an unknown user agent string with an error message or a non-standard HTML (assuming it's an old browser, even though it makes much more sense to assume unknown browsers are good).

Comment: Amazon is not misconfigured, they have their own mysterious reasons for sending what they do.

Answer (score 2):

Your get the same HTML with each request.

Your confusion is coming because you are inspecting the "code the browser gets" in a DOM Inspector. That doesn't show the source code of the page (View > Developer > View Source for that). It shows a serialisation of the current state of the DOM.

JavaScript in the page has changed the `src` of those images after the HTML was parsed.

---

You need to either reverse engineer the JavaScript and then replicate its effects on the HTML you've downloaded **or** execute the JavaScript (e.g. through a headless browser API like CasperJS).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. For the last two days I have been trying Puppeteer with no luck. Scrolling, waiting, selecting ... nothing worked. What is strange is that when I take a screenshot using puppeteer it works fine but when I return the HTML of the DIV it does not return the correct images. https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0001GRVPK/ div('#aplus')